# Convert URL list to linked page titles

Tags: links

I'm looking for a webapp to convert a list of URLs into their respective page titles with links to the respective sites. The output could be either raw HTML or rich text. The tool would of course need to access the remote site and scrape the title of each URL.

For example, the following input:

```
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/07/health/cdc-coronavirus-china.html
https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/07/us/politics/alexander-vindman-gordon-sondland-fired.html
```

would produce the following output: (or alternately its respective HTML source)

[C.D.C. and W.H.O. Offers to Help China Have Been Ignored for Weeks](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/07/health/cdc-coronavirus-china.html)

[Trump Fires Impeachment Witnesses Gordon Sondland and Alexander Vindman in Post-Acquittal Purge](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/07/us/politics/alexander-vindman-gordon-sondland-fired.html)

I modified [harshvchwala's script](https://github.com/harshvchawla/convert-links-to-bookmarks) to do this locally, but would like to find a webapp to do the same.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
echo "usage: $0 <txt file containing list of urls>"
inputFile=${1}
if [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ ! -f ${inputFile} ];then
    echo 'check usage'
    exit -1
fi

outputFile='bookmarks-scripted.html'
echo '<DL>' > $outputFile
NumLines=`wc -l ${inputFile} | cut -d' ' -f1`
currLineNum=0

for eachUrl in `cat ${inputFile}`
do
    let currLineNum=${currLineNum}+1
    echo "processing Line ${currLineNum} of ${NumLines}..."

#    urlTitle=`echo $eachUrl | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev`
    urlTitle=`wget -qO- $eachUrl | perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/title/si'`

    if [ -z ${urlTitle} ];then
        urlTitle=`echo $eachUrl | cut -d'.' -f2`
    fi

    echo ${urlTitle}
    urlLine='<DT><A HREF="'
    urlLine+=${eachUrl}
    urlLine+='">'
    urlLine+=${urlTitle}
    urlLine+='</A>'
    echo ${urlLine} >> $outputFile
    echo
done

echo '</DL>' >> $outputFile
```

Comment: Questions asking for a web application recommendation are off-topic here but you could try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score -1):

What about [Shaarli](https://github.com/shaarli/shaarli)? It's an open source Webapp developed by its community. I personally use it for keeping an eye on valuable hypertexts around the Web, but I'm pretty sure it would match your expectations since you can easily export those informations using an RSS feed. If you're looking for a strict export to HTML, then the bookmark export may be interesting too.

What you still need to do though is to click on each resource Shaarli has to browse and index.